# How To Group Cells With UICollectionReusableView (Using JSON)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm populating my app with JSON off of a Rails app (http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json). Every post in my Rails app has a "release date", and they're grouped by the release date (basically every week there's certain sneakers that release). I want to be able to do the same thing in my app but I'm having difficulty doing that.

On my Storyboard I have a Collection Reusable View with a UICollectionReusableView class and an identifier called "releasesGroup", I also have a label that connects to the UICollectionReusableView called "releasesHeader".

I also want to show the corresponding date in the header, something like this:

[image]

**View Controller**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleaseURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.upcomingReleases = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {
        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        upcomingRelease.release_date = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        [self.upcomingReleases addObject:upcomingRelease];
    }

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UpcomingReleaseCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"UpcomingReleaseCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.upcomingReleases count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UpcomingReleaseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.release_name.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;

    return cell;
}
```

**My UICollectionReusableView**

```
@interface ReleasesGroup : UICollectionReusableView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *releasesHeader;
@end


@implementation ReleasesGroup
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

**my Segue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRelease"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        ReleaseViewController *releaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        releaseViewController.singleRelease = self.upcomingReleases[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

**ReleaseViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UpcomingRelease.h"

@interface ReleaseViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UpcomingRelease *singleRelease;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_price;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_colorway;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_date;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumb;

@end
```

**ReleaseViewController.m**

```
#import "ReleaseViewController.h"

@interface ReleaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReleaseViewController

@synthesize singleRelease = _singleRelease;
@synthesize release_name = _release_name;
@synthesize release_price = _release_price;
@synthesize release_colorway = _release_colorway;
@synthesize release_date = _release_date;
@synthesize thumb = _thumb;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *thumbURL = nil;

    if ([_singleRelease.images isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [_singleRelease.images count])
        thumbURL = [[[[[_singleRelease.images objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"image_file"] objectForKey:@"image_file"] objectForKey:@"medium"] objectForKey:@"url"];

    if (thumbURL)
    {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        self.thumb.image = image;
    }
    else {
        self.thumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cover.png"];
    }

    self.release_name.text = self.singleRelease.release_name;
    self.release_price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _singleRelease.release_price];
    self.release_colorway.text = self.singleRelease.release_colorway;
    self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _singleRelease.formattedDate];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it would appear that you are missing quite a few things. First off: to group the releases by day, you will need some kind of date manipulation, in your viewDidLoad method, you will need to already group the json data into "buckets" corresponding to the release date. Once you have this, the rest is a piece of cake. So onto it:

First off, you'll need a property in your view controller that contains all of the data. Something like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *upReleases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *releaseBuckets;
```

Then, in your `viewDidLoad` method, you'll need to populate this dictionary:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleaseURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    //This is the dateFormatter we'll need to parse the release dates

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSv"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]]; //A bit of an overkill to avoid bugs on different locales

        //Temp array where we'll store the unsorted bucket dates
    NSMutableArray *buckets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {

        //We find the release date from the string
        NSDate *releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"]];

        //We create a new date that ignores everything that is not the actual day
        //(ignoring stuff like the time of the day)
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components =
        [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:releaseDate];

        //This will represent our releases "bucket"
        NSDate *bucket = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //We get the existing objects in the bucket and update it with the latest addition
        NSMutableArray *releasesInBucket = [tmpDict objectForKey:bucket];           
        if (!releasesInBucket){
            releasesInBucket = [NSMutableArray array];
            [buckets addObject:bucket];
        }

        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        upcomingRelease.release_date = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        [releasesInBucket addObject:upcomingRelease];
        [tmpDict setObject:releasesInBucket forKey:bucket];
    }

    [buckets sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate* date1 = obj1;
        NSDate* date2 = obj2;
        //This will sort the dates in ascending order (earlier dates first)
        return [date1 compare:date2];       
        //Use [date2 compare:date1] if you want an descending order
    }];


    self.upReleases = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tmpDict];
    self.releaseBuckets = [NSArray arrayWithArray:buckets];

}
```

Next, you need to have as many sections as the release buckets. Piece of cake:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [self.releaseBuckets count];
}
```

And as many cells for each bucket as the products being released in that date:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.upReleases objectForKey:self.releaseBuckets[section]] count];
}
```

Then, you'll need to set up the header for each section (again, a little bit of date manipulation is necessary to have the right format for your header section):

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ReleasesGroup* releaseGroup = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"releasesGroup" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //We tell the formatter to produce a date in the format "Name-of-the-month day"
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];

    //We read the bucket date and feed it to the date formatter
    NSDate* bucketDate = self.releaseBuckets[indexPath.section];

    releaseGroup.releasesHeader.text = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:bucketDate] uppercaseString];
    return releaseGroup;
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to setup the single cells:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UpcomingReleaseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [self.upReleases objectForKey:self.releaseBuckets[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];

    cell.release_name.text = upcomingRelease.release_name;

    return cell;
}
```

This whole code has been tested and works.

EDITED to include a sorted array for the keys

Comment: I edited the answer, now this code also sorts the release dates for you. You don't need to pay me anything, just accept my answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Now the buckets are grouped correctly, before when I click on a "shoe" it would take me to a detailed view with all the information (name, price, release date, etc) but now my app doesn't parse the information anymore, I get "null" in every field. (I updated my answer so you can see my destinationViewController).